# The better way to import cometD library into LWC

Tags: community, lightning-web-components, streaming-api

I've been trying  to use empAPI on community but unfortunately it's impossible. So I found this staff from trailhead https://github.com/forcedotcom/EMP-Connector.git
Could anyone please describe me basic steps to use this library in my component (i want to use this component inside community)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You do not need EMP-Connector if you are using lwc. Salesforce has a `lightning-emp-api` base component for it (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:empApi).

The lightning/empApi module uses a shared CometD connection.

You can use the provided functions from the module

```
import { subscribe, unsubscribe, onError, setDebugFlag, isEmpEnabled } from 'lightning/empApi';
```

**Update**

**You are right that for communities this component is not supported**.I still suggest you give a try because i have it working at least for aura component in the lightning community builder using emp api. I have not tested the lwc one.

Also push topics might not be supported but platform events are supported in the lightning communities.

One can completely engineer the emp api component with a custom component because under the hood it uses cometd js library.

Here is a sample code to get you started

NOTE - I have used the 3.1.1 version from [here](https://download.cometd.org/cometd-3.1.1-distribution.tar.gz). You can extract the archive and under the common folder just download the comted.js file for using in static resource.

I also uploaded the cometd.js file that i have used for testing. You can get it [here](https://gofile.io/?c=6wLdsC)

Here is the sample code to get started

```
<template>
  <div>Streaming Component</div>
</template>
```

The JS controller is

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track } from "lwc";
import { loadScript } from "lightning/platformResourceLoader";
import cometdlwc from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/cometd";
import getSessionId from '@salesforce/apex/SessionUtil.getSessionId';


export default class Cometdlwc extends LightningElement {
 libInitialized = false;
 @track sessionId;
 @track error;

 @wire(getSessionId)
 wiredSessionId({ error, data }) {
  if (data) {
    console.log(data);
    this.sessionId = data;
    this.error = undefined;
    loadScript(this, cometdlwc)
    .then(() => {
        this.initializecometd()
    });
} else if (error) {
    console.log(error);
    this.error = error;
    this.sessionId = undefined;
  }
}

initializecometd() {

  if (this.libInitialized) {
    return;
  }

 this.libInitialized = true;

 //inintializing cometD object/class
 var cometdlib = new window.org.cometd.CometD();
        
//Calling configure method of cometD class, to setup authentication which will be used in handshaking
  cometdlib.configure({
    url: window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + '/cometd/47.0/',
    requestHeaders: { Authorization: 'OAuth ' + this.sessionId},
    appendMessageTypeToURL : false,
    logLevel: 'debug'
});

cometdlib.websocketEnabled = false;

cometdlib.handshake(function(status) {
            
    if (status.successful) {
        // Successfully connected to the server.
        // Now it is possible to subscribe or send messages
        console.log('Successfully connected to server');
        cometdlib.subscribe('/event/PlatformEvent__e', function (message) {
                  console.log('subscribed to message!'+ message);
       });
    } else {
        /// Cannot handshake with the server, alert user.
        console.error('Error in handshaking: ' + JSON.stringify(status));
     }
   });
  }
}
```

It requires a simple apex controller to get sessionId

```
public with sharing class SessionUtil {

  @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
   public static String getSessionId() {
    return UserInfo.getSessionId();
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, empApi does not work in community

Comment: Empapi unfortunately doesn't support communities

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Yes one can easily re-engineer the component using cometd.js lib in static resource. I have updated the answer

Comment: @pincet just updated the answer to get a sample code.

Comment: @MohithShrivastava What kind of licenses did you use for Community? Cos I wanted to provide updates for Platform Events on Visualforce Community and used lightning:out, but it gave error when I tried to subscribe to updates after handshake

Comment: so I was able to successfully handshake, but got an error when trying to subscribe. Code worked fine in Lightning Experience

Comment: In lightning out it is not supported .what error did you get while subscribing ? Not that in lightning out emp API won't work but you can still use cometd.js to publish and listen

Comment: @MohithShrivastava could U please explain to me this expression - window.org.cometd.CometD()

Comment: @MohithShrivastava here got an error  cometdlib.subscribe(this.channel, response => {
            /// main hook
            console.log('--- inside action');
            console.log(response);
        })  where this.channel = channel = '/data/Employee__ChangeEvent'. The error is 'Exception during execution of message callback Illegal argument type: channel must be a string'

Comment: "channel":"/meta/subscribe","id":"2","subscription":"/event/...","error":"403:denied_by_security_policy:create_denied","successful":false} <br><br>

Comment: window.org.cometd.CometD is a javascript class . It provides various methods like subscribe, unsubscribe and so on

Comment: @MohithShrivastava thanks, I gave up too early) The issue was that I didn't give user Read access to this Platform Event 

Comment: You might want to mark it as answered to help others !!

Comment: @pincet are you sure that you this.channel equals to '/data/Employee__ChangeEvent'? Try passing hard-coded value first, since this seems to be the error

Comment: @ytiq, it was my mistake - I lose the context. Now it's ok

Comment: @MohithShrivastava Did you have any issue with deployment to Prod, I'm currently encountering 403::UnknownClient during 'connect' call. Have you ever encountered that?

Comment: No I have not experienced it ! I suggest you raise a Salesforce support case to see if they can help you resolve it .

Comment: The latest version of cometD doesn't work. downgrading to 3.1.1 resolved my issue. I was getting a handshake issue and then I found this comment
linking another post where reason is explained why https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/197728/cannot-add-property-context-object-is-not-extensible-error-during-cometd-hand

Comment: Late to the party, but I can confirm that e.g. `isEmpEnabled` and subscribe from `lightning-emp-api` just block in a community. Pretty frustrating to have to go build something...

Comment: Hi @MohithShrivastava, Do you thing surfacing the session Id like this would result in a security review fail?

Comment: I am surprised it works with apex returning sessionID! I cannot guarantee as I am not a core member of the team so it’s on the team that looks at it! To me it is ok as I am not using to call any third party api! The other alternative is obviously just throw a visual force page with session ID markup and use apex to grab it or may be use a connected app to grab a sessionID! I think it’s better to set an office hour with security review team and discuss!

Comment: I am getting following ```Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cometd')```. What can I do to avoid this error?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava - I think for clarification in your example code, you might want to change the `cometd.subsribe` call to `cometdlib.subscribe` as the former is resulting in cometd being undefined since 3.1.1 does not look like it sets cometd as a global object.

Comment: @Brandon Franklin Thanks! Just took care of it!

Comment: @MohithShrivastava You say that you were able to use EmpApi for Lightning Components in Communities. Did you do anything special? Because I can't get it to work in the Community while the same code (in a different component) does work in 'internal' Salesforce.

Comment: I did as an aura components few years ago, may now it does not work.

Comment: Thanks for the very fast reply. I'll have to keep searching for a solution..

Comment: Is there a way to do this without a sessionId? 

I'm trying to use a platform event on a site page to update a URL param but the Guest User doesn't have a sessionId.

Comment: No not possible! https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000335516&type=1

Comment: @jonny-harte as mentioned in the link in comment above by Mohith "Before Winter 15, it was possible to get the session id for the guest user by using these codes:" so I set the apex api version like 30.0, I was able to get the session id for guest user, and cometd started working then, but yeah BEWARE, security concerns!

Answer (score 7):

Community licenses don't support Streaming API, therefor empApi doesn't work. Streaming API is based on Push Topics and Read of Push Topics are not supported by Community License (so you can create events, but cannot subscribe to them)

**UPDATE:**
you can subscribe with cometD library, please check comments

Comment: My question was - how can I use CommetD (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/code_sample_java_client_intro.htm) in import for my LWC component? Should I use static resources or something else? I really need som example

Comment: I used another emp-connect library, spent half a day and then found out that it gives an error that you can't use it... (i.e. Community issue)

Comment: was wrong, since I was just missing Permissions to Event. My stupid mistake

Comment: @ytiq were you able to subscribe event in community using AURA/LWC

Comment: yes, I was able to subscribe

Comment: Hey, how did you get this working? Does it still work? No matter what I try, I end up receiving the following error in community: efaultPrevented: false
```Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cometd')```. Using my code somewhere else, it works.

Comment: you need to download cometd and put it into a static resource
https://download.cometd.org/

Comment: Already did that. I import the static resource and then run ```loadScript()``` in my code. When running ```loadScript()``` the line ```root.org.cometd = factory()``` of cometd.js fails.

Comment: try this one https://download.cometd.org/cometd-3.1.1-distribution.tar.gz

Comment: or just load the latest one from here https://download.cometd.org/

Comment: @Gerke - Were you able to get it to work? @ytiq - When using 3.1.1 I get an error that `cometd is not defined` when calling the subscribe method. When I use the latest `7.0.*` the handshaking method fails. Thanks!

Comment: I'll test it today and reply with the version I tested

Comment: @ytiq - I figured it out, the `cometdlib` instance was already created from the library via loadScript so the example code in the above answer just needed to be modified to `cometdlib.subscribe` instead of `cometd.subscribe`. WOOT!

Comment: cool, good that you figured that out

Comment: @ytiq -are you able to subscribe to platform events for guest user site page as well?

Comment: Its working fine for internal user and not working for  guest user. Any alternatives for guestuser ?

Comment: for guest users you need to correctly configure Permissions, from what I remember you need to give access to PushTopic

Answer (score 2):

Just encountered an issue using cometD while working in a LWR community, and the accepted answer didn't work for me.

Don't know why exactly, but getting the session ID from a VisualForce page instead like so fixed it for me:

```
<!-- SessionId.page-->
<apex:page contentType="application/json">
  {"sessionId":"{!$Api.Session_ID}"}
</apex:page>

//SessionUtil.class
public static Map<String,String> getSessionInfo() {

  // render VF page as string, extract JSON data
  Map<String,Object> session_map = (Map<String,Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(Page.SessionId.getContent().toString());

  // return sessionId and url
  return new Map<String,String>{
    'sessionId'=>(String)session_map.get('sessionId'),
    'url'=>URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()
  };

}
```

note, `window.location` doesn't work in LWR, so I captured the URL from Apex too. I used this URL as the base for cometD initialization, which also may have had something to do with this working.