# What CometD streaming channels do communities support?

Tags: javascript, community, lightning-community, streaming-api, cometd

Is there any documentation that says what streaming channels are allowed for communities?

(Note that in communities `lightning-emp-api` methods such as `isEmpEnabled` never resolve but it is possible to [directly load and use CometD JavaScript](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/289584/the-better-way-to-import-cometd-library-into-lwc).)

I'd like to use a [StreamingChannel](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/api_basics/api_basics_streaming) because that **includes user id filtering**. But using [Comet D](https://cometd.org/) JavaScript for a "Customer Community Login" licensed user the response is:

```
{
    "clientId":"1n01i4ijc3vw89e11fi7leljv7xr2",
    "channel":"/meta/subscribe",
    "id":"2",
    "subscription":"/u/CvcpProgress",
    "error":"403::No access on channel",
    "successful":false
}
```

which is [documented](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/streaming_error_codes.htm) to mean:

> The generic streaming channel can’t be accessed because the user
> doesn’t have permissions on the StreamingChannel object.

That object is not present in the profile, and granting rights through a permission set is not allowed:

> The user license doesn't allow the permission: Read Streaming Channels

Trying a Platform Event "/event/cvcp__ProgressEvent__c" the subscribe works:

```
{
    "clientId":"1njst1mjwlem9r8t7qy9p8l9409",
    "channel":"/meta/subscribe",
    "id":"2",
    "subscription":"/event/cvcp__ProgressEvent__e",
    "successful":true
}
```

and the published values are received, but there is no user id filtering for this case. But perhaps this is my only option?

Comment: For documentation you could look below - under experience section you’ll see that community is still not supported yet unfortunately- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:empApi/documentation

Comment: Thanks; yes I've seen that documentation hence the direct use of JavaScript for the Comet D.

Answer (score 0):

look heroku node.js with  streaming channels https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2021/08/how-to-work-within-platform-events-delivery-limits

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce SE! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I second @identigral 's motion. Plus from the [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers) section of the Help Center: _'Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question may be removed. This includes answers that are: ... -barely more than a link to an external site'_.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose CometD version 3.1.0 or later is supported, as they are supported in the Streaming APIs.
For more information please refer to this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/cometd_support.htm).
Please check if your user has access to the platform event object.