# How to subscribe to events from LWC embedded in Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components, platform-event, lightning-out

I have an LWC which subscribes and display a custom Platform Event

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { subscribe, unsubscribe, onError } from 'lightning/empApi';

export default class NotificationsLog extends LightningElement {
    subscription = {};
    events = [];

    connectedCallback() {
        onError(error => {
            console.log('Received error from server: ', JSON.stringify(error));
        });

        subscribe('/event/NotificationReceived__e', -1, this.handleEvent).then(response => {
            this.subscription = response;
        });
    }
}
```

embedded (via Lightning-Out) into a Visualforce page

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:includeLightning />

    <div id="notificationsLog" />

    <script>
        $Lightning.use("c:myApp", () => {
            $Lightning.createComponent("c:notificationsLog", {}, "notificationsLog");
        });
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

I also registered the LWC in the Aura app

```
<aura:application extends="ltng:outApp">
    <aura:dependency resource="markup://c:notificationsLog"/>
</aura:application>
```

---

Nothing happens when I fire such an Event

```
EventBus.publish( new NotificationReceived__e(...));
```

and the root cause seems to be the subscribe is never successful

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me answer my own question. All the others are right with `empApi` doesn't work in a `Lightning-Out` context with a `Visualforce` page. But here is how I actually solved it using **[an already existing CometD LWC component](https://github.com/TheVishnuKumar/lwc-streaming-api)**:

**LWC Markup:**

```
<template>
    <!-- taken from https://github.com/TheVishnuKumar/lwc-streaming-api -->
    <c-lwc_streaming_api 
        channel="/event/NotificationReceived__e" 
        api-version="51.0" 
        debug=true
        onmessage={handleMessage} 
        onerror={handleError} 
        class="cometD">
    </c-lwc_streaming_api>

    Notifications ({events.length}):
    <ul>
        <template for:each={events} for:item="event">
            <li key={event.Id}>{event.txt_Body__c})</li>
        </template>
    </ul>
</template>
```

**LWC JS:**
import { LightningElement, track } from "lwc";

```
export default class NotificationsLog extends LightningElement {

    events = [];

    handleMessage(event){
        this.events.push( event.detail.payload.data.payload );
        this.events = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.events));
    }

    handleError(event){
        console.log( JSON.stringify(event.detail.error) );
    }

    restart(){
        cometD.subscribe();
    }

    destroy(){
        cometD.unsubscribe();
    }

    cometD() {
        return this.template.querySelector('.cometD');
    }
}
```

I am still facing some issues but I am sure I will solve them.

1. Can't find out how to replay events (an option in `empApi` exists for that)
2. The first event fired from the VF page is not displayed

Comment: I was using this code https://gist.github.com/ytiq/8d8cda82397d2cca6c7121163762cc52 with commetd and it seems that you need 'extension' added to support `replyFrom`

Comment: I also asked in the repo how replay works with this LWC https://github.com/TheVishnuKumar/lwc-streaming-api/issues/3

Comment: If I understand you question correctly. Then the same way it works with empApi `replayId` `Indicates what point in the stream to replay events from. Specify -1 to get new events from the tip of the stream, -2 to replay from the last saved event, or a specific event replay ID to get all saved and new events after that ID.` from https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-emp-api/documentation

Comment: when you call `subscribe(channel, replayFrom, callback)` you pass -1, -2 or eventId

Answer (score 6):

Not clear how to interpret "Targets" in the documentation (and where Lightning-Out would fit) but e.g. [lighting-card](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-card) works for these Targets:

- Lightning Experience
- Experience Builder Sites
- Salesforce Mobile App
- Standalone Lightning App

but [lightning-emp-api](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-emp-api) only for this Target:

- Lightning Experience

I had to roll my own CometD (pretty annoying) to have Platform Events working for "Experience Builder Sites". The same may be true for your Lightning-Out case.

Comment: Would you be able to provide sample code of how to make it work with CometD and Lightning-Out?

Comment: Hi @RobertSösemann, As part of my employer's codebase I can't post it, but the starting point was Mohith's post here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/289584/the-better-way-to-import-cometd-library-into-lwc with additions to handle more of the CometD lifecycle. Took a few hours so I suggest you wait to see if anyone answers explicitly about Lightning-Out.

Answer (score 4):

The `lightning/empApi` module is applicable only inside the Lightning Container (You have to be in the Lightning Experience Builder). This is documented in the Targets section in the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-emp-api/documentation).

One reason to avoid using `lightning/empAPI` or even a `CometD` client is that there is a **50K limit** on the [number of event subscriptions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_event_limits.htm) you can have in an org with `Cometd` unless you purchase add-ons. Note this is a shared limit and hence if you have n users using your streaming component effectively your users can subscribe to only `50000/n`. Since it is shared if you have other streaming clients in the org it's lower than that.

If you still think you want to go with the custom implementation using cometd on the platform, check [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/289584/the-better-way-to-import-cometd-library-into-lwc) answer.

What are your options? One of the below should work

1. Maybe go back to traditional polling that executes the query `setInterval` function of JavaScript.
2. Create a Streaming client on Say **Heroku** with [Node.js](https://github.com/websockets/ws) that then opens a WebSocket connection that Salesforce or any other system can listen to. Note that Salesforce itself cannot open a [WebSocket](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.secure_coding_guide.meta/secure_coding_guide/secure_coding_websockets.htm) due to security implications, however, Salesforce can be a client to listen to a WebSocket if CSP is configured for it. This improves efficiency from `n` to 1.